# Comparing cell value to a textbox.text value C#

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-4.0

long story short I have written a comparison for excel iterationh through rows in C# :

```
if(ws.Cells[i, "C"].ToString() == TextBox12.Text)
```

which turns out to be throwing an com hresult exception. What is the right way to do this comparison? I've done extensive searches on the internet but nothing that suits me.
Help needed!

Comment: What HRESULT value does your exception have?

Comment: Exactly this:Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the `.ToString()` method of the `ws.Cells[i,"C"]` object returns the type `System._ComObject`.  You want `ws.Cells[i,"C"].Value.ToString()`.  I tested it, and it found the two were equal.

Comment: well, `ws.Cells[i,"C"].Value.ToString()` doesn't work because I can't see .Value method after I type cell specifications. I tried another way like this:`if (currentFind == ws.Cells.Value2)`(currentfind is an Excel.Range btw) but this time it throws:Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY))

Comment: @Niyazi What do you mean you can't see the Value method?  Since `Cells` is dynamic, you don't get the Intellisense in the IDE, but it's definitely there.  I don't know if the if statement in your comment would actually work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually not that happy with this style of comparison. Could you show me some other way? I'm basically doing this:have an excel file with 100s of rows in it, getting textbox.text and searching with a loop through the end and see if it matches with any value in column C. Any help with that?

Comment: @Niyazi You should probably start a new question, as any new answers anyone will provide on this question will not necessarily match with your original question.

Comment: allright I'll do that, thank @jonsca for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to mark this as solved but I wonder your solution? Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Niyazi The checkmark outline next to the answer.  The thing is, if I answer it here it doesn't benefit anyone else if they are looking for the same information.  But, if that's your choice, I would use the `WorksheetFunction.Match` function (`WorksheetFunction` is a property of your `Application` object).  This way, you are using the spreadsheet's functions to search.